# Refactoring mongoose queries

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I been using mongoose a consider amount and I cant seem to get around "callback hell" and polluting my queries with error treatments.

For example here is a route I have:

```
var homePage = function(req, res) {
        var companyUrl = buildingId = req.params.company

        db.pmModel
            .findOne({ companyUrl: companyUrl })
            .exec(function (err, doc) {
                if (err)
                     return HandleError(req, res, err)

                if( !doc )
                    return NoResult(req, res, {msg: 'Aint there'})

                console.log(doc)

                db.rentalModel
                    .find({ propertyManager: doc.id })
                    .populate('building')
                    .exec(function (err, rentals) {
                        if (err)
                             return HandleError(req, res, err)

                        if( !doc )
                            return NoResult(req, res, {msg: 'Aint there'})

                        console.log(doc)

                        var data = doc.toJSON()

                        data.rentals = rentals

                        res.render('homePage', data)
                    })
            })
    }
```

**my question: is there a more succinct way of writing this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So perhaps what you have above is just a small example, but it doesn't appear to me that there's too much "callback hell" going on in your code (in my opinion).  However, you can certainly refactor your code.  Just know in doing so you can make it more difficult to understand or follow from a maintenance perspective.

One thing you can do is simply refactor your database layer.  If you always find yourself querying one collection and then turning right around and querying another, you could consider merging those collections, or at least the documents that you're looking for.  In a relational database you might separate out these tables and do merges, however in a document-based database, it sometimes makes more sense to combine the data within each document.  This allows for easier queries and simpler logic in your code.

Another solution is to refactor your calls into separate functions, and control the flow in a different way.  A popular library to help with this is [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) which provides many helper functions to assist in the asynchronous world of JavaScript.  There are many to choose from, but one suggestion would be to use the [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) function for your situation (since each call must be made before the next).  It would then look something like this:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        findCompany(companyUrl, callback);
    },
    function(id, callback){
        findPropertyManager(id, callback);
    }
], function (err, rentals) {
   res.render(rentals)
});
```

You would still need to handle the errors in each function, but you could even refactor that out into a helper function.  Furthermore, you could choose to code up something yourself to help with the control flow rather than using async.

But again, the code you showed above is understandable and readable, and only contains a couple inline callbacks.  In this way, there's a lot less going on and may make debugging it later (if things go wrong) easier.

Comment: I should have posted bigger example, lol, I'm trying to get around situations like this where I need to go down 5 models opposed to the 2 above. That's where it's getting painful.

Comment: @delboud I can understand :)  Then the above would still apply -- you could either merge the documents (where possible) or use something like async to better manage your flow of code.  Then refactor your logic into separate functions each responsible for the mongo query, and results in calling the callback with either an error or a result.